# string.match doesn't work in Lua for loop

Tags: for-loop, lua, lua-patterns

I am trying to use a for loop to get author name, id, content of each post in a web forum.
I tried this but it doesn't work. Without the for loop, I will get the first result of the regex in the document.
Any suggestions?

```
for author_id, author_name, author_joined, author_posts, post_date, post_content in
                string.match(content, 
                "<span class=\"name\"><a name=\"(%d-)\"></a><b>([^<]+).-Joined: ([^<]+).-Posts: ([^<]+).-<span class=\"postdetails\">Posted: ([^<]+).-<span class=\"postbody\">(.-)</span><span class=\"postbody\"></span>")
        do
             document:appendContent("Name: " .. author_name)
        end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To be used in a generic `for` loop, you need an iterator, use `string.gmatch` (**global match**) instead of `string.match`.